# Bootstrap responsive columns

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap and I would like the items to align next to each other, so far I have tried using the bootstrap columns but it does not seem to work, I may be writing my code wrong

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h6>
        We've funded 120,000 charity projects for 20M people around the world.
      </h6>

      <h6>
        Clean Water
      </h6>
      <i class="fas fa-tint"></i>
      <p>
        633 million people drink dirty water. With your help we supply clean water which can improve health
      </p>

      <h6>Healthy food</h6>
      <i class="fas fa-seedling"></i>
      <p>
        With your help we have provided good healthy food to the less fortunate.
      </p>

      <h6>
        Education
      </h6>
      <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
      <p>We have developed schools with the donations received, so children can have access to good education</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is how I would like it to look]

The above image is how I would like the design to look

Please help as it is becoming really frustrating.

Comment: You've put all your content in a single column. Why would you expect to see multiple?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this.
Items aligned vertically when browser width is less than 767px.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h6>
    We've funded 120,000 charity projects for 20M people around the world.
  </h6>
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2 mb-md-0">
      <h6>
        Clean Water
      </h6>
      <i class="fas fa-tint"></i>
      <p>
        633 million people drink dirty water. With your help we supply clean water which can improve health
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2 mb-md-0">
      <h6>Healthy food</h6>
      <i class="fas fa-seedling"></i>
      <p>
        With your help we have provided good healthy food to the less fortunate.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2 mb-md-0">
      <h6>
        Education
      </h6>
      <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
      <p>We have developed schools with the donations received, so children can have access to good education</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `col` class with `div` of each column

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h6>
        We've funded 120,000 charity projects for 20M people around the world.
      </h6>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <h6>
        Clean Water
      </h6>
      <i class="fas fa-tint"></i>
      <p>
        633 million people drink dirty water. With your help we supply clean water which can improve health
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h6>Healthy food</h6>
      <i class="fas fa-seedling"></i>
      <p>
        With your help we have provided good healthy food to the less fortunate.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h6>
        Education
      </h6>
      <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
      <p>We have developed schools with the donations received, so children can have access to good education</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would think about it is that you have one row with 4 columns in that row.
As others have pointed out you need to give each Div the code: `class="col-3"`.

The way bootstrap works is by having 12 columns across the page so you would want each of your columns to take up 3 of those columns which is why it is `col-3` if you wanted only 2 columns it would be `col-6` and so on.

For each column you would like side by side it needs to be wrapped in the following code:

```
<div class ="col-3"> 

<div>
```

The letters between  the COL and the number are if you want to specify the screen size that it will scale up to. Leaving it without will also work across all devices.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <i class="fas fa-3x fa-code"></i>
      <div>
        <h5 class="py-2">Clean Code</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div>
        <i class="fas fa-3x fa-cogs"></i>
        <h5 class="py-2">Problem Solving</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <i class="fas fa-3x fa-globe"></i>
      <div>
        <h5 class="py-2">Best Domain</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <i class="fas fa-3x fa-user-shield"></i>
      <div>
        <h5 class="py-2">Secure Website</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer should include some explanation of your changes.